# What is the better solution to display analytics on front end from AWS Opensearch vs Quicksight vs just DynamoDB data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, opensearch, amazon-quicksight

My project is a platform that offers loyalty programs to business owners.
A business can scan customers QR codes and give/retrieve points +  many more actions.

When they scan and submit that new scan with the given points to an API, a lambda is triggered that stores multiple objects (in **DynamoDB**) like:

- a SCAN object
- on the employee that scanned, increments the "scans" attribute for the object that has the curent date
  Example of this type of object:
        `PK                                    SK                        QUANTITY`
  `BUSINESS#<business_id>    <who_scanned_id>#DATE#xx/xx/xxxx              123`
- on the customer that has gained a new number of points, increments the proper attirbute (on that specific date)

What should be the proper approach between these options? Or what else should be a better one?

1. Every time a business owner wants to view some analytics in dashboard, make some requests to **AWS Opensearch**
2. Every time a business owner wants to view some analytics in dashboard, display some embeded diagrams from **AWS Quicksight**
3. Every time a business owner wants to view some analytics in dashboard, make many requests to **DynamoDB** (using API Gateway and Lambda) based on dates and organize the retrieved data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many variables at play to make a recommendation. If it's very frequent use OpenSearch. Less frequent use Quicksight, where you can refresh the data daily for example. And if it's key value look ups, use DynamoDB.